# how to use recursive technique to check value X is a member of list L

Tags: c, recursion

I am not good at recursive programming. I think that this problem is simple but I don't know how to solve it. I need some ideas how to code. Please help me!

How to to check that value X is a member of list L while using the recursive technique?

Comment: This is a bad question. Do you at least know what recursion is?

Comment: This is not very fast or good code in C, but the answer of @Tom Heard is correct. Recursion is way easier in more mathematical/abstract languages like Haskell or other functional programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very rough pseudo code but it would be something like this.

```
int checkList(List L, Value X, int current_index)
{
    if ( List.ValueAt(current_index) == X)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (List.Length == current_index+1)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return checkList(L, X, current_index+1);
}
```

Why does it need to be recursive anyway? It is much better to do this iteratively, as with recursion each function call needs to be added to the memory stack for return information.

Comment: But this function is tail recursive by defintion, so shouldn't the C compiler optimize it by using only one stack frame? Or is this impossible in C?

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve any problem using recursion you just have to think the way of "how to answer my question for some variable X if I know the answer for the smaller values?" - in your case - "How can I test whether the value X is a member of list L if I would already knew if X is a member of list K, which is the *tail* (all elements but the first one) of list L?"

As an example, consider different thing - how to get maximum value of the list of integers using recursion?

1. Maximum value of one element list is its only element, so `MAX( [ x ] ) = x`
2. If i know the maximum of the list K then I know that the maximum of the list composed of K and new value x is simply the bigger of them, so `MAX( [ x | K ] ) = x if x > MAX(K) or MAX(K) otherwise`. Where | is the concatenation operation, so [ 1 2 3 ] = [ 1 | [2 3] ]

Now during execution, such recursion would take first element of the list, and compare it with the biggest from the rest, and call itself recursively till it finds the single list - for which maximum is easy to define. Now you can find the solution of your problem in the same way.